# how to set different fields from observing a publisher?

Tags: android, rx-java

while observing the upload function that sets Ids for pictures in some table I need to set those Ids for `profilePictreId` and `wallpaperPictureId` properties. I didn't find any solutions and flatMap or other functions were too hard to understand. I can get the ids as I mentioned below but I need them to be saparated so I can put them in different fields. either give me a solution or a good document.
don't worry about other functions in code I only need the separation function for Rx while subscribing. thank you

**More Explain:**
after uploading I need two properties to be set but I only should do it in subscribing method `onSuccessUpload`. I tried many ways but I get both Ids set to `profilePictureId` and `wallpaperPictureId` that is a problem they should be separated.

**response for s1 variable:**

```
E/PictureIds@@@>>>: [4e6a3956bf8743b78fe4ffa546f627f0.png]
E/Utils: {"attachments":"4e6a3956bf8743b78fe4ffa546f627f0.png","status":"SUCCESS","message":"-"}

E/PictureIds@@@>>>: [7712b7f081d045e8b94f077e40994290.png]
E/Utils: {"attachments":"7712b7f081d045e8b94f077e40994290.png","status":"SUCCESS","message":"-"}
```

```
private Disposable picture; // this varaibale is set in onSuccessUpload to subscribe 

private void onSuccessUpload(){
setPicture(RxBus.sendResponseUploadLink()
                .subscribe(s1 -> {
                    String[] id = new String[]{s1.getString("attachments")};
                    Timber.tag("PictureIds@@@>>>").e(Arrays.toString(id));
                    setProfilePictureId(id[0]);  // problem is here
                    setWallpaperPictureId(id[1]); // problem is here
                }));
}

private void uploadPicture(String path){
        Upload uploadPicture = new Upload();
        uploadPicture.upload(getToken(), path);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.channel_profile_image:
                selectProfileImage();
                break;
            case R.id.channel_cover_image:
                selectCoverImage();
                break;
            case R.id.submit_social_channel:
                onSuccessUpload();
                uploadPicture(getProfileFilePath());
                uploadPicture(getWallpaperFilePath());
                

        }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't understand what exactly do you want with the response, can you please explain

Comment: I edited my post hope you understand it @hfarhanahmed.

Comment: Also can you post the 's1' the response you are getting for better understanding?

Comment: response added @hfarhanahmed.

Comment: Why is it showing the log of same picture multiple times. just ad Log.d("response", s1.toString()) to see the exact response we are getting from the API.
08-27 11:17:32.563 18071-18071/sanay.co.cleanesn E/PictureIds@@@>>>: [199fd5f269024dcfbc7ba1cb6c38f43a.png]

Comment: sorry it was from LogCat now it's better. @hfarhanahmed

Comment: onSuccessUpload is being called twice, the problem is each time there is only 1 image in attachments and when you call setProfilePictureId and setWallpaperPictureId it will set same image to both functions. BTW aren't you getting any exception here?

Comment: No I don't get any exceptions and I know there is always 1 image in attachments, because the publisher always upload 1 image, now this is the tricky part when I upload the second image how to subscribe `setProfilePictureId()` and `setWallpaperPictureId()` with the corresponding ids in a single observer method?

Comment: you can add type in response i.e {"attachments":"7712b7f081d045e8b94f077e40994290.png","type":"Profile","status":"SUCCESS","message":"-"} and you can add a check if type == Profile then set Profile else wallpaper

Comment: if this solves your problem then let me know so I can post it as answer for the others.

Comment: since I don't have access to database I can't do that. that id comes back from database @hfarhanahmed

Comment: then how are you getting 2 different responses in 1 subscribe method? are you calling 2 different API?

Comment: No, I'm uploading two different pictures and for those 2 uploads I'm getting different responses in 1 subscribe method. There aren't any different APIs.

Comment: Ok, so you are uploading 2 different pictures and subscribe method is same. Now you can have global flags to check which type of image did you uploaded or you can separate subscribe method both diff type of images otherwise there will be no option.

Comment: thanks @hfarhanahmed, this conversation made me realize what's going on with subscribers. I think it's best to set a type in response as you mentioned because controlling flags with 2 different scenarios are complicated.

Comment: Welcome, I thought you already knew that. Please mark the answer correct to help others facing the similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscribe function returns a Subscription object that allows you to manage the created relationship between the observable and the subscriber.

You have only one subscriber so the best thing you can do is to add `imageType` in your API response like,

```
    {
       "attachments":"4e6a3956bf8743b78fe4ffa546f627f0.png",
       "imageType":"Wallpaper"
       "status":"SUCCESS",
       "message":"-"
    }
```

so in the subscriber you can differentiate between your uploaded images and call different functions accordingly.